# Showing master view on some pages and preventing the user from hiding it

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an iPad app with a `UISplitviewController` set as the root view controller of `UIWindow`. The master view controller (i.e. the view controller of the left view) is the `UISplitViewController's` delegate with the delegate method `shouldHideViewController` returns `YES`,  this means when the app first launches the left view will be hidden and can be shown (and hidden)  by the user gesture, i want to show the master view when i navigate to detail pages and prevent the user from hiding it using the gesture, i've tried to call `shouldHideViewController` method on the delegate to let it returns `NO` the second time it got called but this time it has no effect, the master view keeps hidden in detail pages and can be shown with the user gesture.
any ideas to achieve showing of the master view with this scenario would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This may only be a partial answer because I'm not sure what you mean that you call shouldHideViewController method on the delegate. My understanding is that only the UISplitView should call this method. If you call it, then it will not effect the UISplitView, because it wasn't what made the call. In other words, the delegate method is used by UISplitView to get some information (and allow you a place to do additional things to other stuff) but it is not used as a way to tell the UISplitView what to perform.

Having said that, at least for the gesture activation/deactivation, I would think that in  splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation: you could do something like

```
[svc setPresentsWithGesture:NO];
```

I don't see any way to programmatically tell the UISplitViewController to display or hide the master view controller because the delegate only tells it if it should proceed in presenting or hiding the master when it is going to try and do that. It does seem like there should be a way to do this though.